# Javascript matrix that triples elements

Tags: javascript, matrix

I'm trying to write a program that runs a matrix

`[[1,2],[3,4]]`

and triples the elements via a function

For example:

Input

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Output

```
[[3,6],[9,12]]
```

Comment: Show us your attempt at least.

Comment: Have you ever written any code that iterates through an array?

Comment: Write a code that iterates through the matrix and multiplies by 3 each value. Try it yourself, don't just copy/paste the answers. It wont help you become a better developer .

Comment: Also, if one of the answers works for you, remember to accept it. If multiple answers works, accept the one that is cleaner and easier to understand for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to iterate the columns of the matrix, than iterate each row of these columns.

```js
const matrix = [
 [1, 2],
 [3, 4]
]

const output = []

for (const col of matrix)
{
 const triples = []
 output.push(triples)
 
 for (const row of col)
 {
  triples.push(row * 3)
 }
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: nice approach for cols and rows

Answer (score 2):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) to  modify array elements

```js
const matrix = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
];

const newMatrix = matrix.map(el => el.map(el => el * 3))

console.log(newMatrix);
```

Comment: Just for clarification, I'd give proper names to variables, but the use of nested `Array.map()` is classy!

Answer (score 2):

A simple iteration would work

```
for (var i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
    matrix[i][j] *= 3;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a better formatting... The current snippet is incredibly hard to read.